# Express middleware, next and Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

There is very simple Express router with handler:

```
router.get('/users/:userId/roles/:roleId', function(req, res, next){
    const roleId = req.params.roleId;
    res.rest.resource = UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId}).exec().then(function(usr) {
        console.log(req.params.roleId); // => undefined
        console.log(roleId);            // => okay here
        const result = usr.roles.find( role => String(role._id) === String(roleId));
        return result;
    });
    next();
});
```

As it seen accessing `req.params.roleId` within promise returnes `undefined`. This is true only for cases when `next()` called outside promise's `then`.

I'm okay with asyncing and promises and understand that `next()` will be called before handler in `then`. But what happening with `req.params.roleId`? Why and where it mutates? Does middleware called by `next()` gets same but mutated `req`?

Note: `res.rest.resource` used by middleware called later to build right REST-like response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code as it is is kind of indeterministic in its execution.

*Something* mutates the role ID in the `next()` handler, and since it takes a while for `findOne()` to eventually dispatch to the `then` handler, that mutation has already happened.

Without knowing further details of your app, it looks like this might be the correct implementation.

```
router.get('/users/:userId/roles/:roleId', function(req, res, next) {
    const roleId = req.params.roleId;
    UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.userId}).exec().then((usr) => {
        const result = usr.roles.find(role => String(role._id) === String(roleId));
        res.rest.resource = result;
        next(); // <-- only dispatch to next after we find the resource result
    });
});
```

### Edit:

I dug a little deeper. See this little example app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var v = 0 | +new Date();
    console.log("middleware 1 setting foos to ", v);
    req.params.foo = v;
    req.foo = v;
    next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("middleware 2 reading foos and starting timer:", req.params.foo, req.foo);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("middleware 2: foos are now", req.params.foo, req.foo);
    }, 1000);
    next();
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("params = " + JSON.stringify(req.params) + " and foo = " + req.foo);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The output for a request is

```
middleware 1 setting foos to  -902674369
middleware 2 reading foos and starting timer: undefined -902674369
middleware 2: foos are now undefined -902674369
middleware 1 setting foos to  -902673113
middleware 2 reading foos and starting timer: undefined -902673113
middleware 2: foos are now undefined -902673113
```

and the browser output is `params = {} and foo = -902673113`, so it turns out that **you are not allowed to touch `req.params`**, but you can add any other properties to the `req` object and they will travel along fine.

This seems to be because of the route matching layer rewriting `params` on each step.

Comment: why not just put the `next()` inside a `finally()` in the promise chain? This way the `next()` call is always guaranteed.

Comment: @AKX Pulling `next()` into promise with setting `res.rest.resource` seems to be smart idea, thanks.

Comment: @AKX do you know what `next()` exactly does? Looks like once `next()` called in current middleware all data available for this middleware become unsafe, mutative and not accessible.

Comment: @AlexPovar `next()` just dispatches to the next middleware or handler in the chain... but see the example I added :)