# passing variable to next middleware in req in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pass variable to the next middlewares through the `req` object.
getting some data from database and passing that data to request for next middlewares to use.

```
User.findone({ _id: someId })
    .then(user => { req.user = user })
    .catch(err => {  })
```

After that then and catch block i am using `next()`.
Therefore for the next middlewares i am getting req.user undefined.
but if i pass the `next()` function in the then block after
`req.user = user` like `.then(user=> {req.user = user; next()})` than i am getting `req.user` a valid user object to use for the next middlewares.
what is the reason for this behaviour??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express middleware, next and Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297384/express-middleware-next-and-promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `User.findOne` function is asynchronous. The result of that function is only known in the `then` block.

```js
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: someId })
        .then(user => {
            req.user = user;
        })
        .catch(err => { });
    next(); // If you put next() here, the request will go straight to the next middleware without waiting for User.findOne() to complete.
};
```

```js
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: someId })
        .then(user => {
            req.user = user;
            next(); // Putting next() here is correct
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(err); // Remember to handle error to avoid hanging the request
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`then...` is called after the `User.findone` promise resolves. Thus, if you put `next()` outside of `then`, it will be called before `then`.

You could read more details at [promise-basics](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)

Alternatively try to use [async-await](https://javascript.info/async-await) as it looks more straightforward.